# Adding an image and a textblock control inside a DataGridTemplateColumn header

Tags: wpf, xaml, c#-4.0, wpfdatagrid

In our WPF application, we have a screen where we display a grid, the column's header right now is a Text, I'm supposed to add an image beside the text. This is the XAML code,

```
<Custom:DataGrid.Columns>
       <Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{Binding EmailIDHeader, Source={StaticResource LiteralDictionary}}" Width = "0.1*" CellTemplate="{StaticResource EmailIDTemplate}" SortMemberPath="EmailID"/>
 </Custom:DataGrid.Columns>

<DataTemplate x:Key="EmailIDTemplate">
        <Grid MinWidth="10" Margin="5,0,5,0">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Text="{Binding customerItem.EmailID}" Margin="0,0,3,0"/>
        </Grid>
```

EMailIDHeader will load the Text value for the Header, I have to add an image beside it. How do I achieve this? I tried the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27942374/how-to-add-an-image-to-a-datagridtemplatecolumn-header). But this just shows me an empty header column.

Comment: Share the `EmailIDTemplate` code you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a `DataTemplate` where you organize your textblock and your image as desired, and set the property `HeaderTemplate` with this resource.

The data template for the header:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="EmailIDHeaderTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Image Source="SPhotoEditor-20170120_075433.jpg" Width="20" Height="20"></Image>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Text="{Binding EmailIDHeader, Source={StaticResource LiteralDictionary}}" Margin="0,0,3,0"/>

        </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

For the cell :

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="EmailIDTemplate">
    <Grid MinWidth="10" Margin="5,0,5,0">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Text="{Binding customerItem.EmailID}" Margin="0,0,3,0"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Your grid :

```
<Custom:DataGrid.Columns>
   <Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn  HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource EmailIDHeaderTemplate}" CellTemplate="{StaticResource EmailIDTemplate}" Width = "0.1*"  SortMemberPath="EmailID"/>
</Custom:DataGrid.Columns>
```

[image]

Comment: This is not working, the header comes empty. I tried placing two textblocks inside instead of image, that is also not coming :(

Comment: Why there is somme "Custom" tag in front of your controls. Are they some kind of customized controls inherited from Datagrid and DataGridTemplatecolumn ? Because n a standard data grid it works like a charm (I've implemented the code i provided before posting it)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the model is

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string _value;
    public string Value{ get { return _value; } set { _value = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Value"); } }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void RaisePropertyChanged(string propname)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propname));
    }
}
```

and there are two properties in the View Model:

```
    string _name;
    public string Name { get { return _name; } set { _name = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Name"); } }


    string _imagePath;
    public string ImagePath { get { return _imagePath; } set { _imagePath = value; RaisePropertyChanged("ImagePath"); } }
```

You can use the following View:

```
    <DataGrid DataContext="{Binding}" ItemsSource="{Binding Models}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.Name}"/>
                            <Image Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.ImagePath}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```